# Bootstrap 3 - can I make right column have same height as left one with css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using Bootstrap 3 in my project and have a row with two panels side by side. What I'd like to achieve is to make the right panel have same height as left one.

Having two columns of the same height is not the problem. As you can see in the code provided below, it's already done. The real problem is that:

1. Left panel should fit the content.
2. If right panel has content which exceeds left panel's height, a scrollbar should appear.

And now the question comes: I was wondering if there is any pure CSS solution with which I can achieve this? Note that left column's height can change so assigning fixed height to columns won't resolve the problem. I've already tried a few different solutions, but none worked.

Here is my current code:

**Html**

```
<div class="row flex-row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Some<br><br>
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Some<br><br><br>
        longer<br><br><br>
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-row, .flex-row > div[class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 0 auto;
    flex: 0 auto;
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;

    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g1u8u98g/2/

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think when height varies, that's not possible with just pure css. js is required.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give separate class name to right panel like 'rgt'

and in CSS put :

```
.rgt{
    height: 90px;
    overflow-y:  scroll;
}
```

Remove those styling you already done if not necessary

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I said, content of the left column may change dynamically, so assigning a fixed height doesn't entirely resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Give separate classes and give style as :

```
 .lft{
      height:100%;
     }
 .rgt{
      height:100%;
      overflow-y:scroll;
     }
```

then add script as :

```
<script>
    $('.rgt').css('height', $('.lft').height() + 'px');
</script>
```

Comment: Again, thank you for the answer. Although it might help somebody in other situation, my goal of asking the question was to find a pure CSS solution which would suit my case. Javascript solution is more complicated as I'm loading data to first panel asynchronously and using Angular as a framework (which adds another delays connected with applying changes in the view). However, I think I can handle JS solution myself which I am not able to do with pure CSS.